# How to conditionally show global Storybook argTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

In Storybook 6 my components have common properties such as theme, size, etc. which apply to 90% of my components. I want to define the controls for those props in a global way so I don't have to duplicate it for each story.

This works when you define [global argTypes](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes#global-argtypes) however if a component does *not* have one of these props, Storybook still renders the prop in the table but does not show any control for it.

How do I prevent the prop from being rendered at **all** in the props table but still be defined in a global way?

Comment: What a great question. I'm currently following this: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11697 , which will hopefully give an answer someday.